# Create hidden ID field using React-Admin in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-admin

I am trying to use the `SimpleFormIterator` in the React-Admin module to create a list of children records from the parent record edit form.

So I've setup a `SimpleFormIterator` component with the details of the child record, however, this doesn't return back an ID, so when I submit the form no ID for the child is maintained. This can be seen below:

```
<SimpleFormIterator>
    {/* Want a hidden ID field here */}
    <SelectInput label="Type" source="type" choices={ ... } />
    <SelectInput label="Reason" source="reason" choices={ ... } />
    <DateInput label="Date" source="date" />
</SimpleFormIterator>
```

General HTML code would suggest I need a hidden input to store the ID, however, I can't work out a way to do this using React-Admin.

I've tried adding a `TextInput` component into the `SimpleFormIterator`, such as:

```
<TextInput source="id" hidden />
```

But the input is not hidden for some reason, it is shown to the client.

I've also thought to use the `key` property of the `SimpleFormIterator` but I don't know how to access the current list of elements to directly access the ID value.

What am I missing, why is the field showing, or is there another way to maintain the ID against that child record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand perfectly what you want to do.

But you can hide your TextInput the following way:

```
<TextInput source="id" style={{display:'none'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

to create a hidden field in react-native you can use the folloing code.

```
 <TextInput
    source="id"
    style={{
     position: 'absolute',
     width: 0,
     height: 0,
     zIndex: -100,
     backgroundColor: '#0000',
    }}
 />
```